Realizable singular value spectra of normalized finite frames
$\DeclareMathOperator\tr{tr}$Let $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$, $m \geq n$, and let $\{f_i\}$, $1 \leq i \leq m$, be $m$ unit vectors (wrt. 2-norm) in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $A = [f_1 \, \, \, f_2 \, \, \, \ldots \, \, \, f_m]^T$ be the $m \times n$ matrix having $f_i^T$ as its $i$th row vector.
Now let's apply singular value decomposition to $A$:
$$A = U \Sigma V^T,$$
where the $m \times m$ matrix $U$ and the $n \times n$ matrix $V$ are orthogonal and the $m \times n$ matrix $\Sigma$ has the form:
$$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1 & 0 & \ldots& \ldots & 0 \\
0 & \sigma_2 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \ldots & 0 & \sigma_{n-1} & 0 \\
0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & \sigma_n \\
0 & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & & & & \vdots \\
0 & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
The non-negative $\sigma_i$ are the singular values of $A$, which satisfy the condition $\sigma_1^2 + \ldots + \sigma_n^2 = m$. This follows from the trace of the $m \times m$ Gram matrix $G$ of $A^T$:
$$G = A A^T = U \Sigma \Sigma^T U^T.$$
All diagonal elements of $G$ are $1$ thanks to the $f_i$ being unit vectors. This shows $\tr(G) = m$, but we also have $\tr(G) = \tr(U \Sigma \Sigma^T U^T) = \tr(\Sigma \Sigma^T) = \sigma_1^2 + \ldots + \sigma_n^2$. The question now is:
Is every singular value spectrum $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_n$ which satisfies the trace constraint $\sigma_1^2 + \ldots + \sigma_n^2 = m$ a realizable spectrum, i.e., is there a $m \times n$ matrix $A$ (having unit vectors as rows) which has the given singular values $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_n$ as its singular value spectrum?
If $\operatorname{rank}(A) = n$, the $\{f_i\}$ form a so-called frame, i.e., each ${\bf v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ can be represented as a linear combination of elements of $\{f_i\}$, but the representation has not to be unique. Using the terminology of frame theory, the question becomes:
What are the realizable singular value spectra of normalized finite frames?
